# How to export test plans from QA Director?

Tags: manual-testing, test-data, export

How can I export test execution plans from QA Director?

I know that there is a report called Execution/Execution Plans, which can export the execution plan itself. However, this information by itself is not useful, since I need the additional information which tests are associated with the test plan.

I have tried the "Configure" functionality and use the "Asset" tab to add the tests as the second level. Unfortunately the second level is disabled (greyed out).

[image: Test Execution Plan Report Configuration]

Is there a way to export the test plans in a way that I can associate the tests with them?